# SpringBoot 3 TestRestTemplate error when endpoint returns 400

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm using `SpringBoot 3.2.1`. I'm using `TestRestTemplate` to call the service on IT tests.

I have one service that would return `400 (Bad Request)` when there are validation issues. I call this endpoint using `TestRestTemplate` in the following way (it is 400 as the password format is invalid, not unauthorised etc):

```
    @Autowired
    lateinit var testRestTemplate: TestRestTemplate
...
...
...
    @Test
    fun signIn_InvalidPassword() {

        val headers = HttpHeaders()
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        val body = AuthenticationRequest(email = "user@email.com", password = "password")
        val httpRequest: HttpEntity<AuthenticationRequest> = HttpEntity(body, headers)

        val result = testRestTemplate.postForEntity("/auth/signin", httpRequest, String::class.java)
        assertThat(result.statusCode, equalTo(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST))
    }
```

I know the endpoint is actually returning `400` and used the debugger to make sure it goes to the right places.

But the test is failing with the following error:

```
I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:51571/auth/signin": cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode
```

I do not have any specific config for `TestRestTemplate`. Just what comes with `SpringBootTest` out of the box.

Comment: what type of authentication mechanism is used on the server ?

Comment: I have `spring-boot-starter-security:3.21` . And I'm using a custom JWT filter to check. But ofcourse it doesn't reach there as the field validation fails first